# Pass password for proxy server in Maven2 through command line or prompt?

Tags: java, maven-2, proxy-server

As I'm uncomfortable storing my username and password (must auth to the proxy server with my normal login credentials) in plaintext in `.m2/settings.xml`, I'm trying to see if there is a better way to pass my credentials.

What I've tried

- Relying on system proxy settings - didn't work (obviously)
- Leaving out password - downloaded 5k - 740b jars. Right...
- Adding `-Dmaven.proxy.password=mypass` to command line - Same as above

is there anyway I can pass this information over command line? Or even better, is there a way to have it prompt me for the password?

FYI, it works as expected when I do have the password in the configuration file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used this particular feature of Maven, but they do have some support for encrypting passwords in your settings.xml.  You can read more here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

That doesn't exactly answer your question, but it might solve your root problem.